# How to evaluate Probability of Y?

Tags: normal-distribution, standardization, sum

[image: Question Layout]

Hi all,

It's my first undergraduate statistics module as a business major and I've encountered some difficulties in computing the response to the question.

I have several queries below:

1. Would Y have to represented in terms of Z?
2. Would it be better to perform the summation or expansion of the Xj term first?
3. Would the Expectation of Y and Variance of Y be required to compute P(Y > 1.61)?
4. Wouldn't the Expectation of Y = 0 and Variance of Y = 1 since its variables are Z, which is a standard normal variable?
5. Are there 2 different answers for P(Y > 1.61)?

Many thanks in advance and cheers!

Comment: Is it $X = 4Z -1$ or $X_j = 2Z_j -1?$ (Problem is a little easier if it's the latter.) We like to see what you have tried on your own before giving answers. // Try expressing $Y$ in terms of $Z_j.$ Hint: What do you know about chi-squared distributions?

Comment: Thanks for responding! It is Xj=2Zj−1. // If Y is expressed in terms of Zj, then Y = summation(4Zj^2), upper limit = 5, lower limit = 1. // Hmm, as far as my knowledge goes, chi-squared distributions mean that the upper limit, which is 5 here, is the degrees of freedom. Does this mean the E(Y) = m and Var(Y) = 2m? Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to be a regular participant, suggest you 'take the tour'. Maybe you even get a few points for that. But its suggestions about good Q & A are worthwhile. // As soon as I saw $Z^2$ with standard normal $Z,$ I thought of chi-sq. Upper limit is 5, which is number $Z_j^2$'s summed. That's what makes DF = 5. // Yes to E(Y) and Var(Y) as in my Note (2), but the simulation results are only approximations. With 100,000 iterations you get only 1 or 2 of places of accuracy.

Comment: Ok, touring sounds great! Especially with the Q&A Tips. // Ah so a Z^2 indicates Chi-sq, this looks like a good rule of thumb in future. // Noted on E(Y) and Var(Y)'s approximations, but I'm allowed to approximate them to 1 s.f. or 1 d.p. in my responses. // I also obtained the probability by looking up a chi-sq table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reply with your thoughts. You're getting closer.

After a bit of simplification, I got $Y = \sum_{j=1}^5 Z_i^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 5).$
Then using R instead of a printed table of chi-squared distributions, I got
$P(Y > 1.61) \approx 0.90.$

```
1 - pchisq(1.61, 5)
[1] 0.9000374
qchisq(.1, 5)
[1] 1.610308
```

*Notes:* (1) In R, `pchisq` is a chi-squared CDF, and `qchisq` is an inverse CDF (quantile) function.
(2) The chi-squared distribution with $\nu$ 'degrees of freedom' is defined as the distribution of the
sum of squares of $\nu$ independent standard normal random variables.
(3) If $Q \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu),$ then $E(Q) = \nu,$ $Var(Q) = 2\nu.$
(4) Density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(5).$

[image]

```
curve(dchisq(x,5), 0, 20, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", xlab="q", 
      main="Density of CHISQ(5)")
 abline(v=0, col="green2"); abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 1.61, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

(5) Simulation of $\mathsf{Chisq}(5)$ as the sum of squares of five
standard normals.

```
set.seed(2020)
q = replicate(10^5, sum(rnorm(5)^2))
mean(q)
[1] 4.984788  # aprx E(Q) = 5
var(q)
[1] 9.977126  # aprx Var(Q) = 10

hist(q, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Simulated Dist'n of CHISq(5)")
     curve(dchisq(x,5),add=T,lwd=2,col="brown")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive review! I think the Y Summation equation is useful. // But how did you know Y followed a chi-square instead of a normal distribution? // The Density function of Chisq(5) graph looks great! // I am not too familiar with R but I perceive that the dotted red line is 1.61, therefore only the area to its right is considered, which is about 90% of all observations. // Also, I see that the Expectation and Variance of Y is actually 4.984788 and 9.977126. I would upvote but I have not attained 15 rep points. Above all, thanks for the very thorough analysis of my question!

Comment: Great work - cheers !